# PHP detect if file is webp image

Tags: php, gd, webp

I'm trying to check if a file is a webp image in PHP

```
if (false != imagecreatefromwebp($filename)) {
            //do something
        }
```

But I get the following error

```
Warning: imagecreatefromwebp(): 'test.webp' is not a valid WEBP file
```

Same file can be successfully converted to jpg using online converts and
I can also see that the file is actually a webp from the bytes

```
RIFF�5WEBPVP8X....
```

Comment: Maybe post a link to it so folks can check it for you...

Answer (score 1):

[PHP manual : exif_imagetype](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

```
<?php

if (exif_imagetype($filename) === IMAGETYPE_WEBP) {
    echo 'The picture is webp!';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

`$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->buffer($filename);`

Answer (score -1):

The GD library throws a lot of warnings, even when it shouldn't do so. I'd use in this particular case the [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) operator in front of `imagecreatefromwebp()`

```
<?php
$img = @imagecreatefromwebp($filename);
var_dump($img);
```

Now it will return an image resource identifier on success and boolean false on error.